# Changing text in DOM dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dom

Am working on an application whereby I have some data in a Javascript 
object which I have pulled from the backend. 
Am trying to iterate through the Javascript object and populate 
in the DOM inside a ul but it aint working, the ul has existing text that I want
to change instantly after loop.

**Javascript object copied from browser console tab**

```
0: "Mathematics"
​
1: "English"
​
2: "Swahili"
​
3: "Germany"
```

**Logic**

```
$.each(planDetails, function (key, value) { 
    $("#packageBenefits ul li" + key).text(value);
});
```

**Markup to populate data into**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">All subjects</div>
    <div class="card-body" id="packageBenefits">
        <ul>
            <li><span> Mathematics </span> </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum .............. </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are currently saying is target an element that is within an li, that is within an ul, that is within another element with id `packageBenefits`. No such element exists so you are not updating your text. Rather than looping through the list of values to fill, try properly grabbing the group of li's you want to update and loop through that.

Comment: What is value of `plainDetails`? Well, `$("#packageBenefits ul li" + key)` is going to generate something like `#packageBenefits ul li1`. Maybe you want something like: `$("#packageBenefits ul li:nth-child(" + key +")")`?

Comment: Will there be always enough `<li>` elements (one for every entry in `planDetails`)? And what is `planDetails` exactly? An object (`{}`) or an array (`[]`)?

Comment: @Andreas It is an array

Comment: And my first question?

Comment: @Andreas No the <li> will be dynamic

Comment: Does the script have to add/remove `<li>`s according to the content of `planDetails`? Not enough? -> Add missing. Too many? -> Remove unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method in jQuery...

```js
var planDetails = ["Mathematics","English","Swahili","Germany"];
$.each(planDetails, function (key, value) { 
  $("#packageBenefits ul li").eq(key).text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">All subjects</div>
    <div class="card-body" id="packageBenefits">
        <ul>
            <li><span> Mathematics </span> </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum .............. </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will get the `nth` object, and set the text value accordingly.

---

A minor improvement on the above would be to get the objects once outside of the `$.each`, otherwise jQuery has to find all the objects on each individual call of the `$.each` function, and then get the `nth` item...

```js
var planDetails = ["Mathematics","English","Swahili","Germany"];
var $lis = $("#packageBenefits ul li");
$.each(planDetails, function (key, value) { 
  $lis.eq(key).text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">All subjects</div>
    <div class="card-body" id="packageBenefits">
        <ul>
            <li><span> Mathematics </span> </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum .............. </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If, as @scrappedcola suggests in their comment, you want it to start updating from the 2nd item... it's simply a case of doing `+1` on the `.eq(key)`...

```js
var planDetails = ["Mathematics","English","Swahili","Germany"];
var $lis = $("#packageBenefits ul li");
$.each(planDetails, function (key, value) { 
  $lis.eq(key+1).text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">All subjects</div>
    <div class="card-body" id="packageBenefits">
        <ul>
            <li><span> Mathematics </span> </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum ............... </li>
            <li>lorem ipsum .............. </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though op will probably want to increment the index by 1 to bypass the li that contains the span. Also should check that the li that you are grabbing exists before trying to insert or it will error out.

Comment: @scrappedcola _"the ul has existing text that I want to change instantly after loop"_ - I'm not quite sure why it has to be "after" the loop, but the existing text should be changed.

Comment: @scrappedcola - I wasn't 100% sure, as their first array entry is already `Mathematics`... but you might be right.  However you're wrong about needing to check the `li` exists... jquery will still pass back a collection of elements from `.eq()` and you're just setting `.text` on an empty set

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var planDetails = { 
  0: "Mathematics",
  1: "English",
  2: "Swahili",
  3: "Germany"
}

$('.card-body li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).html(planDetails[index]);
});
```

JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/j67L4tk9/1/